# Using if/else in the smarty template system?

Tags: php, smarty

I'm new to using the smarty template system and was hoping someone could help me with this.

If `{$clientsdetails.customfields1}` is null OR blank, I want it to show the message "not working".  If there's anything entered in that field, I want it to show the message "currently working".

Comment: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.if.tpl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
{if $clientsdetails.customfields1==""}
    not working
{else}
    currently working
{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{if empty($clientsdetails.customfields1)}
    <p>Not Working</p>
{else}
    <p>Currently Working</p>
{/if}
```

This will check if $clientsdetails.customfields1 is not set or if it equals false.

In PHP all of these are considered to be false:

- false
- 0
- 0.0
- ""
- "0"
- null

If it is not set or == false, it will show 'Not Working' otherwise 'Currently Working'

Documentation for more Information: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.if.tpl